# See if a number has already been drawn

Tags: c, arrays, random, compare, do-while

I have an issue understanding the "do - while" statement in C.

Here is the complete code: http://pastebin.com/uPRvRscd

The program generates 6 numbers ranged from 0 to 50.
None of the 6 numbers repeats.

This is the do-while loop:

```
for(c=0;c<BALLS;c++)
{
    /* See if a number has been allready been drawn */
    do
    {
        ball = rand() % RANGE; /* Generate the random ball */
    }
    while(numbers[ball]); /* How is this compare made ? */
    /* Number drawn */
    numbers[ball] = 1; /* What is this for ?!?  */
    printf("%2d ", ball+1); /* add 1 to ball so ball won't be zero */
}
```

- How does the logical compare work ?

I know that the DO depends if the WHILE is true or false.

`numbers[ball] = 1;` What is this supposed to do ? ( if i remove it the result is the same )

Thank you

Comment: FYI, this code "could" run forever if your random function isn't random enough.  I always fixed code like this when I find it...

Comment: "if i remove it the result is the same": try getting 49 (or 50) random balls from the range of 50 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C has a rule that "anything that is zero" is false, everything else is true. So when you write `if(x)` it is the same as `if (x != 0)` and `if(!x)` means `if (x == 0)`.

Same wit conditions in `for`, `while` and `do` - `while`.

So your code does:

```
do
{
    ball = rand() % RANGE; /* Generate the random ball */
}
while(numbers[ball] != 0);
```

I assume that `numbers` is an array of 50, that is filled with zero [if it's of static storage duration, then it's automatically set to zero if nothing else is stated.]

When a number has been drawn `numbers[ball] = 1;` sets that number to non-zero, so if we draw the same number again, the do-while loop will loop again and pick another number [we hope - if the random number generator is really rubbish, it may turn into an infinite loop]

Answer (score 1):

```
for(c=0; c<50; c++) {
    do {
        ball = rand() % RANGE;
    } while(numbers[ball]);

    numbers[ball] = 1;
    printf("%2d ", ball + 1);
}
```

---

If we were to remove the line: `numbers[ball] = 1;`, then it is possible that ball will have the same value on multiple iterations of the main `for` loop. This would cause the program to report 50 numbers, just like before, except now, there **CAN** be duplicates.

---

As to the conditional in the while loop, these two lines are equivalent.

```
1. do { ... } while(numbers[ball]);
2. do { ... } while(numbers[ball] != 0);
```

---

This could would also be better, if more descriptive variable names were used. In particular, `numbers`, is more accurately labeled as `already_selected_balls`.

Answer (score 0):

see your `ball = rand() % RANGE;` generates numbers between 0 to 9 (your Range being 10)
initially numbers array is initialised to zero , indicating no numbers is drawn so far.

now random statement chooses a number (it may be zero also) then by `while(numbers[ball])` you check if that number is already drawn or not ( 0 is false, everything else is true), initially every one was 0 so do-while loop will stop and we set `numbers[ball] = 1;` to indicate the number ball is already used, now the program prints `ball+1` (since ball can be 0 also, and we don't want ball number to be zero)

assume at first number 5 was chosen (and 6 was printed ), now assume `rand()` again generate 5, this will satisfy condition of while (numbers[5] being 1) do-while runs again till it finds a number which is never used (indicated by numbers[ball] being zero)

basically that `ball+1` statement is optional since writer of code don't want ball number to be 0